# Multiplication.

Tags: math-history

Is there any other way to visualise multiplication apart from *repetitive addition*. I've been thinking about it for quite a while now that we're introduced to multiplication as solely *repetitive addition* in the lower grades. Is that approach correct? Is there any other way to visualise it?

Comment: If we are talking about the lower grades, how about "if you have 3 piles of 5 apples, how many apples do you have in total?"

Comment: Area/volumes/hypervolumes of shapes? That's how ancient Greeks used to think of numbers in general

Comment: Think of it as scaling? Like stretching an elastic rod or something.

Comment: @SBareS Isn't that repetitive addition again?

Comment: How about areas?  Is that repeated addition?  Sure you can put your rectangle on a grid and count the boxes, but what is going on in your head?  Another mental model is a change in scale.  And if you were multiplying by a fraction, do you think of that as repeated addition?

Comment: @AngeloRedina Somehow that's a bit non intuitive to me. I needed an intuitive way to wrap my head around multiplication.

Comment: @DougM Isn't that repetitive addition of infinitesimals?

Comment: @SBareS I'm a high school student. It might sound stupid that I'm concerned about such 'trivial' things. But the this is one of the things we're taught as something which is _true_ in the lower grades. And we never question it later...

Comment: @AngeloRedina How was multiplication defined? What was the intuition behind it is my primary concern.

Comment: Peano defined multiplication as an operation that is associative and distributes over addition.  It is never defined as "repeated addition" but due to that distributive property, over the natural numbers, that is exactly what it is.

Comment: You could try reading Euclid's elements (http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/elements.html or Wikipedia). For a short answer, if you have a rectangle whose sides are long 5 and 6, you define 5*6 as the area of said rectangle. If you had square tiles of side 1, this means that you could fit exactly 30 tiles inside your rectangle. Of course today we would see that area as 30m^2 (or whatever unit you want to use) and the number of tiles as 30 (pure number).

Comment: @DougM Just something times something. It just struck him? What'd he aim to explain?

Comment: @AngeloRedina It's something we define for our convenience- areas/volumes stuff? So that's the reason *multiplication* is what it is? To define the properties of area and volumes and other geometrical constructs.

Comment: Sure $a(b+c) = ab + ac.$  What kind of objects are $a,b,c?$  Doesn't matter!  His goal was to put arithmetic on a firm theoretical foundation.  As you move on to linear algebra, abstract algebra or complex analysis, there are new forms of multiplication.  Forms of multiplication that may not be commutative.  But all distribute over addition.

Comment: "Somehow that's a bit non intuitive to me. I needed an intuitive way to wrap my head around multiplication."  Why?  If you need an intuitive idea then what's wrong with repetitive addition?  That is how it arose after all.  It's *defined* purely abstractly as ***any*** method of combining to objects to get an object that follows certain rules.  I could define a  knight times a bishop equals a rook if I wanted to (and it followed my rules). As such, repetitive addition, area calculation, combining rearrangements of sets, rotating by angles,etc. all satisfy the rules and can be multimplication.

Comment: I actually like stretching things longer and scaling things.  Not sure why that is unintuitive to you.  I like it because it avoids the mistake that you can't multiply 2 apples with 3 oranges.  I also like area and work and physics problems because it always that if there *were* any meaningful way to conceptualize an "apple-orange" (as there are ways to conceptualize foot-pounds and man-hours) then you *could* multiply 2 apples by 3 oranges.   Yes, they are repetitive addition on infintisimals (not really) but ... what's wrong with that.

Comment: @fleablood I think I understand why scaling _was_ unintuitive to me. I think it was because I was trying to start off with the **unit** we already defined when I scaled it. When we define a unit and say that something is, say, five times that unit, we mean that that quantity is five _of_ that unit or five units. We start from nothing and take five units. What I was doing was that I was starting from the 1 unit I defined and that's why it seemed confusing. Maybe it was because I was trying to compute the difference bw the initial and final values and somehow relate it to multiplication.

Comment: @fleablood I hope I'm thinking in the right direction now. If not. Let me know. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have recently been teaching this concept to my own child (about first grade math). My explanations have revolved around a couple of concrete representations.

1. **Length of rods**

   We use [Cuisenaire rods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuisenaire_rods) to make arithmetic operations more concrete. So, for multiplication if you have five rods of length 2, say the child can see and feel that that is the "same" as one rod of length 10. I'm amazed at how quickly my child has learned the corresponding lengths of these rods and can quickly do arithmetic by saying something to the effect of "a brown, and two reds makes ..."
2. **Area of geometric figures**

   This is very similar to 1. This may use the rods again, but the pattern would be arranged in a rectangle. The question I ask in this case is something to the effect, "if we have five rows of green rods, how many white rods (unit length) is that equivalent to?"
3. **Counting groups of fingers**

   This has actually worked the best for my child. For $3 \times 2$ for example, I just hold up two hands with three fingers each. We can then count them. Of course, you don't need to use fingers, apples work just as well.

I recognize that many of these have the potential to fall back on the idea of repeated addition but I don't think that is necessarily a bad thing. Mathematics is all about building abstractions. As one concept becomes more concrete (addition in this case), it becomes a block to build upon with further abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

a geometric way could use Thales' theorem and look at the multiplication as a "stretch" of the original value. This would be useful when you start multiplying for numbers between 0 and 1, since it shows that the result could be **less** than the number you start with.

[image]